# Does C++ have a dictionary similar to Objective-C's NSDictionary?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, dictionary, nsdictionary

As the title says, is there a dictionary similar to Objective-C's `NSDictionary` for C++? I just need a data structure that holds a (key,value) pair and can be added and retrieved.

Comment: [Also known as Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) which, well, maps keys to values. Generally though, as with an NSDictionary, the access is expected to be O(1) or similar but this is *not* required of the Map ADT (so be sure to consult the documentation for restrictions, requirements, and expected behavior).

Comment: the O(1) version in C++ is std::unordered_map

Comment: You will be thrilled to discover the magic of operator overloading, a feature that is glaringly absent from Objective-C and that only terrible people who hate productivity argue against. Every time I type 'objectForKey' or 'setObject ... forKey' I die a little inside. At least I don't have to type all of it every time thanks to autocomplete.

Comment: @Suboptimus totally agree, and luckily the days of 'objectForKey' will soon end, see [this](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html).

Comment: @Suboptimus Have you seen [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)? Xcode 4.5 will have `NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"name": @"Jeffery" };` to define literal dictionaries and `NSString *me = dict[@"name"];` to get values from dictionaries (and more).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use std::map.

For example, to map from integers to std::string:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
  my_map[3] = "hello";
  my_map[4] = "world";

  std::cout << my_map[3] << " " << my_map[4] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use std::map or std::unordered_map (NSDictionary is unordered) in C++, however there is one major difference. Because the standard template libraries use templates for the value types, your map will be locked into one type each for both the key and the value. With NSDictionary, since everything is based off of NSObject, you can mix and match types.

If your data is homogenous, then you are all set. If you need that mixed-type behavior, you will need to create a custom class that can contain or derive into all of the types you wish to use.

Answer (score 4):

Check out std::map in the standard template library.  It will do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Others have answered your question already and I have +1'd them. Still having a feeling that  there is a little bit more information out there that might be useful, here I go, too.

Yes, C++ has [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). However, it is an ordered associative container with O(log n) search/insert complexity. Oftentimes, a hash table is preferred. For that purpose there is [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with O(1) best case lookup.

Oftentimes, hash tables are preferred over the sorted trees (though not always). If performance matters to you, a standard C++ hash table implementation might not fit you well. After all, it is extremely generic. So you might want to take a look at [Google Sparse Hash](http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/) project - it provides a dense hash and a sparse hash implementations that boost your performance and have theirs tradeoffs (i.e. speed vs memory etc), see [documentation](http://sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html) for more.

I am not sure how serious you are about learning C++, but in case you do want to learn it a bit more, you will be surprised with its rich set of other different containers and algorithms. I've once found SGI's STL documentation and have been using it for more than decade now, so I recommend it to you as well - http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html. It could be  just a little bit outdated, though, but is very useful. That is what C++ comes with out of the box. On top it, check out Boost, a set of different libraries that are not part of the standard library - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'd plus 1 but I don't have enough reputation >: (